# Sort Behavior of Table View in JavaFX

Tags: java, database, user-interface, javafx-2

I intend to write an JFX-Application that displays data from database tables that contain up to 1M entries. Unfortunately, the standard API makes it difficult to support lazy loading. Reading the whole table is not an option (even though it performs well up to 100K entries).

Paging can be accomplished using a custom list class provided as model to the TableView. However, I also need to control the sorting behaviour of the TableView, since in my case, this would be left to the dbms.

An ugly solution is to make the columns unsortable, and add a Click-Event listener to the Column-Header. Apart from the coding, this also makes it impossible to display the current sort order in the usual way.

It is possible to listen to a change to columnSortOrder, but the standard sorting mechanism is still applied. What I would like to be able to do is display the standard ascending/descending icon in the column header while having full control of the sort behaviour of the TableView.

[**Edit**: In short, I want to implement *lazy loading*. I want a TableView that behaves exactly like normal TableView but does not sort the list when the user clicks on a column header. However, the sort order should still be displayed in the column header label.]

Is that somehow possible to achieve?

Many thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: If you have concrete suggestions, you may file a jira issue in javafx jira : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: In particular, what is the improvement you want, to have lazy loading support?

Comment: @AlexanderKirov i think that he wants lazy loading suport fot `TableView`

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry which API? The question is that - this can be added as feature in javafx, if it worth that. Or as extension in.. I don't know.. jfxtras.org, or smwhere else.

Answer (score 0):

For reference:

This has been added to JavaFX-8. One can use `TableView.setSortPolicy(...)` to customize sorting.